# Create a new variable in pre-existing column

Tags: r

I am a beginner of R and I would like to create a new variable "Overall" and "Profit (sum of profits of 1st and 2nd term per company) under each column

```
Company Term Profit
   A    1st   300
   B    1st   400
   A    2nd   500
   B    2nd   200
```

Comment: AJI , dive into tidyverse , especialy dplyr package which is made to manipulate data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my solution.

```
library(dplyr)

test_data = read.table(
    text = "
Company Term Profit
   A    1st   300
   B    1st   400
   A    2nd   500
   B    2nd   200
",
    header = TRUE,
    
)


test_data = test_data %>% 
    left_join(
        test_data %>% 
        group_by(Company) %>% 
        summarise(Overall = sum(Profit)),
        by = "Company"
    )

OP:
  Company Term Profit Overall
1       A  1st    300     800
2       B  1st    400     600
3       A  2nd    500     800
4       B  2nd    200     600
```

Answer (score 0):

use ***dplyr*** package for data manipulation
specify grouping parameters and use mutate() to create additional variable

```
# let this be your data
df = read.delim('x.txt', sep = ',')

data.frame(df) %>% 
group_by(Company, Term) %>%
  mutate(`Sum of profits` = sum(Profit))
```

ouput:

```
  Company Term      Profit `Sum of profits`
  <chr>   <chr>      <int>            <int>
1   "A"    "1st"      300              300
2   "B"    "1st"      400              400
3   "A"    "2nd"      500              500
4   "B"    "2nd"      200              200
```